# How can I get Google Cloud plugin to work in Goland and PyCharm.?

Tags: google-cloud-intellij

I'd like to get the Google Cloud Tools plugin to work with PyCharm and Goland

I downloaded the plugin's .zip, and pointed each IDE at it, and installed it. In each case, I receive the following error:

```
Plugin Error
            Problems found loading plugins:
            Plugin "Google Cloud Tools" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle" not installed.
            Disable Google Cloud Tools
            Open plugin manager
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to circle back here to let everyone know this support is now available. You can visit the plugin's home page here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-cloud-code/ it is installable as a standard plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Features that are language agnostic such as cloud repos and the GCS browser should be available in PyCharm and Goland in our April or May releases.

[You can track the work to support this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1896)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Google Cloud Tools plugin had a hard dependency on the Grade plugin. You should raise an issue with the maintainers of the Google Cloud Tools plugin and ask them to make the Grade dependency optional. The other solution would be to switch to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.